# Index a View in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there any way I can build an index for a view in SQLite?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2009-05/msg00683.html) from a frequent online SQLite commenter says no:

```
>Hi
>
>May I know if we can create index on a View?

You can't create an index on a VIEW.
A VIEW can be seen as a stored SELECT statement. 

>Thanks in advance.
>wying
-- 
( Kees Nuyt
)
```

Comment: Strangely, I see in my logs that sqlite will automatically create an index for a view under the covers, depending on usage!

Answer (score 9):

Accessing a view will use the indexes defined on the underlying tables in the view, if those indexes meet the selection and filtering criteria.

So, even though you cannot define an index on a SQlite view, table indexes may still be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the statement

`SELECT Something FROM (Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Something) WHERE (Field = 'text')`

runs a lot faster than subsituting the join by the view.

Comment: @Miguel Because it does not satisfy [subquery flattening conditions](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening).